# How does one configure Kogito to fire BPMN Notifications?

Tags: notifications, bpmn, kogito

I have an extremely basic BPMN2 diagram that is being served by a local Kogito instance. I can move through the various tasks without issue.

A single user task has a notification configured to send an email. This notification configuration was created with the VS Code Tools provided by Kogito. Below is the XML generated for the notification in the bpmn2 file.

```
<bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
    <bpmn2:targetRef>_26A2A9B8-5A6F-4D0B-A388-66795F520516_NotStartedNotifyInputX</bpmn2:targetRef>
    <bpmn2:assignment>
        <bpmn2:from xsi:type="bpmn2:tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[[from:|tousers:|togroups:|toemails:person@place.com|replyTo:|subject:Hello world|body:I wish I wish this email would fire.]@[PT1M]]]></bpmn2:from>
        <bpmn2:to xsi:type="bpmn2:tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[_26A2A9B8-5A6F-4D0B-A388-66795F520516_NotStartedNotifyInputX]]></bpmn2:to>
    </bpmn2:assignment>
</bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
```

I've dug through the Kogito documentation and examples and could not find a way to configure notifications. Is this something that is supported and just needs to be configured? At the very least is there an event that I can write a listener for to send the email myself?

Answer (score 0):

its old question though, have you tried service task to execute notification of your choice?

it might not available at the time of question, but now we can run this based on our flow

now user task has notification too

for editor based notification we have API now for different channels, see link

https://blog.kie.org/2021/02/kogito-notifications-api.html